# Positions of coinciding bits

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given squarefree $N\in\mathbb Z$ what is the maximum fraction of factors (not necessarily prime) that have $r\in(0,1)$ fraction of their bit positions having same value?

What if squarefreeness is relaxed?

Comment: Given any positive integer $n$, no matter how large, and any $r$, $0<r<1$, I can write down $n$ bitstrings such that each pair has proportion $r$ of its bits identical. So there no maximum number of factors.

Comment: Maximum fraction of factors.

Comment: Each bitstring can be interpreted as a positive integer written in binary, and $N$ is then the product of those numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean the following. Fix some coordinate positions. An integer can have only so many factors. What is the maximum fraction of them agreeing at these coordinates?